# Building a typing game in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

a few days back i started reading Head first C#, i use visual c# 2015 for building code and learning C# but however the book is based on visual studio 2010, i never ran into any problem  so far while learning until i ran into this exercise when i have to build a typing game, i followed all the procedure as mentioned by the book and built it with no errors. but in the end when i run the code a key press from the keyboard should initialize the game but nothing seems t o start the game not even a mouse click or even from virtual keyboard.

**Here is the code**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication15{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Random random = new Random();
    Stats stats = new Stats();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add((Keys)random.Next(65, 70));
        if (listBox1.Items.Count > 7)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox1.Items.Add("Game over");
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if  (listBox1.Items.Contains(e.KeyCode))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Remove(e.KeyCode);
            listBox1.Refresh();
            if (timer1.Interval > 400)
                timer1.Interval -= 10;
            if (timer1.Interval > 250)
                timer1.Interval -= 7;
            if (timer1.Interval > 100)
                timer1.Interval -= 2;
            difficultyProgressBar.Value = 800 - timer1.Interval;

            stats.Update(true);           
        }
        else
        {
            stats.Update(false);
        }
        correctLabel.Text = "Correct:" + stats.Correct;
        missedLabel.Text = "Missed:" + stats.Missed;
        totalLabel.Text = "Total:" + stats.Total;
        accuracyLabel.Text = "Accuracy:" + stats.Accuracy + "%";
    }
}
```

}

**class for the code**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication15{
class Stats
{
    public int Total = 0;
    public int Missed = 0;
    public int Correct = 0;
    public int Accuracy = 0;

    public void Update(bool correctKey)
    {
        Total++;
        if (!correctKey)
        {
            Missed++;
        }
        else
        {
            Correct++;
        }
        Accuracy = 100 * Correct / (Missed + Correct);
    }
}
```

}

**Form designer code**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication15{
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
        this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
        this.statusStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip();
        this.correctLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel();
        this.missedLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel();
        this.totalLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel();
        this.accuracyLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel();
        this.toolStripStatusLabel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel();
        this.difficultyProgressBar = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProgressBar();
        this.statusStrip1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // listBox1
        // 
        this.listBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.listBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 80.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.listBox1.ItemHeight = 120;
        this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.listBox1.MultiColumn = true;
        this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
        this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(887, 261);
        this.listBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // timer1
        // 
        this.timer1.Interval = 800;
        this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        // 
        // statusStrip1
        // 
        this.statusStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this.correctLabel,
        this.missedLabel,
        this.totalLabel,
        this.accuracyLabel,
        this.toolStripStatusLabel1,
        this.difficultyProgressBar});
        this.statusStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 239);
        this.statusStrip1.Name = "statusStrip1";
        this.statusStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(887, 22);
        this.statusStrip1.SizingGrip = false;
        this.statusStrip1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.statusStrip1.Text = "statusStrip1";
        // 
        // correctLabel
        // 
        this.correctLabel.Name = "correctLabel";
        this.correctLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(58, 17);
        this.correctLabel.Text = "Correct: 0";
        // 
        // missedLabel
        // 
        this.missedLabel.Name = "missedLabel";
        this.missedLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(56, 17);
        this.missedLabel.Text = "Missed: 0";
        // 
        // totalLabel
        // 
        this.totalLabel.Name = "totalLabel";
        this.totalLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(45, 17);
        this.totalLabel.Text = "Total: 0";
        // 
        // accuracyLabel
        // 
        this.accuracyLabel.Name = "accuracyLabel";
        this.accuracyLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(78, 17);
        this.accuracyLabel.Text = "Accuracy: 0%";
        // 
        // toolStripStatusLabel1
        // 
        this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Name = "toolStripStatusLabel1";
        this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(533, 17);
        this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Spring = true;
        this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Difficulty";
        this.toolStripStatusLabel1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        // 
        // difficultyProgressBar
        // 
        this.difficultyProgressBar.Name = "difficultyProgressBar";
        this.difficultyProgressBar.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 16);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(887, 261);
        this.Controls.Add(this.statusStrip1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);
        this.statusStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.statusStrip1.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip statusStrip1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel correctLabel;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel missedLabel;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel totalLabel;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel accuracyLabel;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel toolStripStatusLabel1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProgressBar difficultyProgressBar;
}
```

}

I just started learning C# and working with visual studio this month, i don't know much about programming
My guess is the problem lies some where with the  KeyDown event
[image]

Comment: Did you try to place a breakpoint on the first line of the `Form1_KeyDown` method (click in the left margin (should be in a different color)) ?
Once you do, run your application, the program execution will pause when the program actually reach this line, allowing you to check line by line the program execution flow

Answer (score 2):

In all of that code I cannot see where timer1 is started - try adding

```
timer1.Start();
```

after InitializeComponent();

Comment: If I read the OP correctly, the `Start` call should be in the `KeyDown` Event, don't you think ?

Comment: Possibly a better place - but I do think that is what the issue is.

Comment: I think it might be this too, just wanted to add a precision concerning where it should start to best answers the OP needs :)

Comment: I also tried your solution by adding timer1.Start(); and disable the timer behavior in properties, it worked as well. Does this  line of code forces the timer1 to enable ?

Comment: I think the timer is enabled by default - so Sidewinder94's idea of putting the start in the KeyDown event is probably a good idea - it may need an additional Boolean to prevent doing it multiple times. Note that the timer can be enabled & not started.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple - your input focus is on the listbox. The guy who wrote the sample probably didn't test it all that much, or you didn't follow the procedure precisely enough :)

To make sure the form receives key press on a child control, you need to set the form's `KeyPreview` property to `true`.

Also, as PaulF noted, you never start the timer. The simplest solution is to set `Enabled` to true.

Comment: IIRC, if the Listbos does not handle the KeyDown Event, shouldn't it be propagated to the parent control ?

Comment: @Sidewinder94 Well, the listbox does handle the keydown event. That's how you can control the listbox with your keyboard, after all.

Comment: Thank you, guess i didn't the timer behavior to enable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to this, but here's what I've got.  I'm working through the same book and ran into the same problem, which is that the instructions tell you to set the listbox font at 72pt size.  This makes the letters too large to display properly in the listbox on the form, and the Dock Fill property (or some other property, I'm new at C#) causes the ListBox (and its contents) to not display on the form during runtime.

The fix was to reduce ListBox1's font size down to the next size down, at 48pt.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I had to set the timer to start or enabled and also set the font size to 48pt.
Add one of these lines in Form1.cs underneath InitializeComponent().

```
this.timer1.Enabled = true; 
this.timer1.Start();
```